# In WordPress, the blog posts widget doesn't display my recent posts on the home page - how can I fix it?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a blog page which will have all the posts but I also want to have the blog posts widget on the main page. When I am in the editor, it shows the posts that I have currently made but then when I view the live page, there is nothing featured. I thought posts would show chronologically anyway but I think the theme has a separate homepage which I am trying to not use.

I don't know if it is the theme I am using, Adventurer, or some issue that I can't seem to notice but I have tried quite a lot to get them to appear.

Editor:
[image]

Live site:
[image]

I have tried selecting specific posts, reducing the number of posts to the actual number I have on the blog, different viewing methods but nothing will actually get the posts to feature on the website.